# Need help in attempting to color simple candlesticks in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

[This type of bars is used by stockcharts.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0SPi.png)

The way it works is that black bars and red hollow bars would be a pivot point.

Cant figure out how to code this into trading view.
Appreciate any help if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `plotcandle()` function. You can change the color of the candles, wicks and borders.

To create a hollow candle, just create a color with 100 transparency.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

color border_color = if (close > close[1])
    color.black
else
    color.red
    
color fill_color = if (close > open)
    color.new(color.white, 100)
else
    if (close > close[1])
        color.black
    else
        color.red
        
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, "My candles", fill_color, border_color, bordercolor=border_color)
```

Below two charts are the same. I disabled the regular candles on the bottom one and added my own script.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: ive tried it like this     //  indicator("blackfilledRedhollow", overlay=true)

BlackHollow() => close > close[1] and close > open

RedHollow() => close < close[1] and close > open

BlackFilled() => close > close[1] and close < open

RedFilled() => close < close[1] and close < open


barcolor(BlackHollow() ? color.green : na)  
barcolor(RedHollow() ? color.white : na)  
barcolor(BlackFilled() ? color.black : na)  
barcolor(RedFilled() ? color.red : na)

Comment: It didn't work?

Comment: It worked very nicely thank you, my reputation is too low to upvote

Comment: No worries. Glad I was able to help.